# Bootstrap 3 - Aligning nested column height with a longer column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm designing a site using bootstrap 3 and I've been having an issue with aligning portlets.  This is what the site currently looks like when the browser is perfectly positioned:

[image: I want]

The above picture is a decent example of how I want it to look.  I'd like the Dates Portlet to match the combined height of the Purchase Task Details portlet and Purchase Costs portlet.  Ideally it would extend to the bottom of the purchase costs portlet.  Similarly, I'd like the approvals portlet to match the height and positioning of the Tracking Portlet.

I've tried a number of solutions, but nothing seems to work.  Instead, I usually get something that looks like this:

[image: I have]

Here's the code I'm using (Please ignore the needs fixing):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- BEGIN OUTTER COLUMN -->
<div class="col-md-9 sol-sm-9">
  <div class="row ">
    <!-- START PORTLET -->
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <div class="portlet purple-seance box">
        <div class="portlet-title">
          <div class="caption">
            <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>Purchase Task Details</div>
          <div class="actions">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
              <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="portlet-body">
          <div class="row static-info">
            <div class="col-md-3 name">Purchase Status:</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 value">
              <span class="label label-success"> !!! NEEDS FIXIN !!! </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 name">Assigned To:</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 value">!!! NEEDS FIXIN !!!</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row static-info">
            <div class="col-md-3 name">Order Type:</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 value">!!! NEEDS FIXIN !!!</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 name">Order:</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 value">!!! NEEDS FIXIN !!!</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row static-info">
            <div class="col-md-3 name">Procurement Ticket</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 value">!!! NEEDS FIXIN !!!</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 name">Ready Id:</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 value">!!! NEEDS FIXIN !!!</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row static-info">
            <div class="col-md-3 name">Vender:</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 value">!!! NEEDS FIXIN !!!</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 name">Manufacturer:</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 value">!!! NEEDS FIXIN !!!</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row static-info">
            <div class="col-md-3 name">Location:</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 value">!!! NEEDS FIXIN !!!</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 name">PO Number:</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 value">!!! NEEDS FIXIN !!!</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row static-info">
            <div class="col-md-3 name">SAP Contract Number:</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 value">!!! NEEDS FIXIN !!!</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 name">SAP Contract Line Number:</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 value">!!! NEEDS FIXIN !!!</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- END PORTLET -->
    </div>
    <!-- END ROW -->
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <!-- BEGIN INNER COLUMN -->
    <div class="cold-md-9">
      <!-- START PORTLET -->
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="portlet blue-steel box">
          <div class="portlet-title">
            <div class="caption">
              <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>Deal Structure</div>
            <div class="actions">
              <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="portlet-body">
            <div class="row static-info">
              <div class="col-md-5 name">Deal NRR:</div>
              <div class="col-md-7 value">!!! NEEDS FIXIN !!!</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row static-info">
              <div class="col-md-5 name">Deal MMR:</div>
              <div class="col-md-7 value">!!! NEEDS FIXIN !!!</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row static-info">
              <div class="col-md-5 name">Deal Term:</div>
              <div class="col-md-7 value">!!! NEEDS FIXIN !!!
                <span class="label label-info label-sm"> ROI  </span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row static-info">
              <div class="col-md-5 name">Deal Total:</div>
              <div class="col-md-7 value">!!! NEEDS FIXIN !!!
                <span class="label label-info label-sm"> $ </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END PORTLET-->
      </div>
      <!-- START PORTLET -->
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="portlet red-mint box">
          <div class="portlet-title">
            <div class="caption">
              <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>Purchase Costs</div>
            <div class="actions">
              <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="portlet-body">
            <div class="row static-info">
              <div class="col-md-5 name">PR NRC:</div>
              <div class="col-md-7 value">!!! NEEDS FIXIN !!!</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row static-info">
              <div class="col-md-5 name">PR MRC:</div>
              <div class="col-md-7 value">!!! NEEDS FIXIN !!!</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row static-info">
              <div class="col-md-5 name">Amount:</div>
              <div class="col-md-7 value">!!! NEEDS FIXIN !!!</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row static-info">
              <div class="col-md-7">
                </br>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END PORTLET -->
        <!-- END INNER COLUMN -->
      </div>
      <!-- END ROW -->
    </div>
    <!-- START PORTLET -->
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="portlet green-jungle box">
        <div class="portlet-title">
          <div class="caption">
            <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>Justification</div>
          <div class="actions">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
              <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="portlet-body" style="display: block;">
          <div class="panel-group accordion" id="accordion1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapse_1" aria-expanded="false"> Rationale </a>
                    </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse_1" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p>Example information</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapse_2" aria-expanded="false"> Notes </a>
                    </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse_2" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
                <div class="panel-body" style="height:200px; overflow-y:auto;">
                  <p>CSCC Quote #14182705</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- START PORTLET -->
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="portlet green-jungle box">
        <div class="portlet-title">
          <div class="caption">
            <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>Tracking</div>
          <div class="actions">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
              <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="portlet-body" style="display: block;">
          <div class="panel-group accordion" id="accordion1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapse_3" aria-expanded="false"> FedEx </a>
                    </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse_3" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="row static-info">
                    <div class="col-md-3 name">Tracking:</div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 value">1111-2222-3333-4444</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row static-info">
                    <div class="col-md-3 name">ETA:</div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 value">Aug, 8, 2016</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapse_4" aria-expanded="false"> DHL </a>
                    </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse_4" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
                <div class="panel-body" style="height:200px; overflow-y:auto;">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row static-info">
                      <div class="col-md-3 name">Tracking:</div>
                      <div class="col-md-6 value">1111-2222-3333-4444</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row static-info">
                      <div class="col-md-3 name">ETA:</div>
                      <div class="col-md-6 value">Aug, 8, 2016</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END OUTTER COLUMN -->
</div>
<!-- START PORTLET -->
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
  <div class="portlet purple-medium box">
    <div class="portlet-title">
      <div class="caption">
        <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>Dates</div>
      <div class="actions">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
          <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="portlet-body">
      <div class="row static-info">
        <div class="col-md-5 name">Purchase Task Created:</div>
        <div class="col-md-7 value">!!! NEEDS FIXIN !!!</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row static-info">
        <div class="col-md-5 name">Ticket Received:</div>
        <div class="col-md-7 value">!!! NEEDS FIXIN !!!</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row static-info">
        <div class="col-md-5 name">Quote Received:</div>
        <div class="col-md-7 value">!!! NEEDS FIXIN !!!</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row static-info">
        <div class="col-md-5 name">PO Issued:</div>
        <div class="col-md-7 value">!!! NEEDS FIXIN !!!</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row static-info">
        <div class="col-md-5 name">Change Order Date:</div>
        <div class="col-md-7 value">!!! NEEDS FIXIN !!!</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row static-info">
        <div class="col-md-5 name">Order Received Date:</div>
        <div class="col-md-7 value">!!! NEEDS FIXIN !!!</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row static-info">
        <div class="col-md-5 name">Lasted Modified:</div>
        <div class="col-md-7 value">!!! NEEDS FIXIN !!!</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row static-info">
        <div class="col-md-5 name">Last Modified By:</div>
        <div class="col-md-7 value">!!! NEEDS FIXIN !!!</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END PORTLET -->
</div>
<!-- START PORTLET -->
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
  <div class="portlet green-jungle box">
    <div class="portlet-title">
      <div class="caption">
        <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>Approvals</div>
      <div class="actions">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
          <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="portlet-body">
      <div class="row static-info">
        <div class="col-md-4 name">Approved by:</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 value">!!! NEEDS FIXIN !!!</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 value">!!! NEEDS FIXIN !!!</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row static-info">
        <div class="col-md-4 name">Approved by:</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 value">!!! NEEDS FIXIN !!!</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 value">!!! NEEDS FIXIN !!!</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END PORTLET -->
</div>
<!-- END TAB -->
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I've been wracking my brain over this for a while now.  I appreciate any assistance anyone can provide.  Thanks!

Comment: a minimal demo would be preferred

Comment: I don't believe you can achieve this using Bootstrap out-of-the-box.  You will need to use Tables or Flex to fix this using HTML5/CSS3.  You could also use Javascript to find the height of the taller column and set the height of the shorter one programmatically.  Sorry I don't have time to write a better response, but any of those three approaches will work.